# Xml documents should never be passed as String, how to motivate?

Tags: c#, java, xml

I feel strong discomfort when seeing method signatures like the following:

```
public void foo(String theXml);
```

What will `foo` fo if passed a String beginning with an UTF-16 XML declaration?
In my opinion, XML should be typed as either a strong XML type, like a DOM-tree or a byte-array. Thus, foo should be redeclared as:

```
public void foo(Byte[] theXml);
```

Generally, the programmer will needlessly assume, when reading `theXml` has a certain encoding. Often just hoping that the default one for the file library will guess correctly.

**How can I motivate this to my colleagues?**

Incompatible document-header encoding declarations is too weak a motivation. (Using strong type or a byte-array will discourage from naïve parsing/modification of the document.) I've seen numerous times where encoding breaks due to this kind of error.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure there's a test in your test suite which will fail if XML is wrongly handled in a String. If explaining the problem doesn't motivate, showing it happening might ...

Comment: Thank you, that's a good answer. I was looking for something a b it more theoretical though. Maybe even philosophical.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a theoretical problem; more a practical one. Some western developers working with XML initially have a blind spot to the complexities of character and encoding issues. Working with content which has a good wide repertoire of 'special' characters reinforces the point that these issues exist; and from there it follows some ways must exist to handle them - and from there the solution is to understand the technology ...

Answer (score 6):

Passing XML as a `String` is no more wrong than passing it as a `byte[]` - if the input is already decoded, you can happily ignore the decoding hints in the processing directives. You worry about making incorrect assumptions about encodings, but if you use strings, encodings are a non-issue since you don't have to decode anything. (Someone could of course be constructing the strings from raw bytes and make incorrect assumptions at that point, which of course *would* be a problem. But then again, if you take a `byte[]` argument, someone might already have a string and convert it to bytes using an incorrect charset.)

Parsing string input isn't stranger than parsing input from a decoding source like `java.io.Reader` or `System.IO.TextReader` (most XML parsers let you do so), which brings us to another topic: **I would recommend against passing unparsed XML as strings or byte arrays altogether** - you get more flexibility if you work with `InputStream`s (for sources you don't know the encoding of) and `Reader`s (if you do know the encoding, or if the data for some reason doesn't need to be decoded). You also get the benefit that the whole document doesn't need to reside in memory before it's parsed.

So, instead of this:

```
public void foo(String theXml);
public void foo(byte[] theXml);
// Usage:
foo("<document />");
foo("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><document />".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

... you'd have:

```
public void foo(Reader source);
public void foo(InputStream source);
// Usage:
foo(new StringReader("<document />"));
foo(new ByteArrayInputStream("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><document />"
                             .getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the ones that ignore the importance of encoding will just work around your suggestion by using: `foo(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(theString))`. And the next one will probably make a wrapper for your class so they can just go back to using `string` again.

I guess that at some point care has to be taken to have some things be done correct and protecting against those who do not wish to write correct code might be a battle lost before you start.

Personally i actually always found the fact that we declare the encoding in the encoded datastream a bit odd. But that's pretty theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

I actually agree with your colleagues. There is not really a good argument for this, unless you want to save memory but then its unreadable in debugging. Encoding should be checked before it's being passed around, no matter the type.

If you however create or use a wrapper you can argue that the code is cleaner.